# How to append a new span using jQuery in the JavaScript based game code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to edit a snippet that needs a new span to be appended to an existing game board whenever the combination of the codebreaker is wrong it should show black, white or empty marble.

I think that there is some problem in the resulting span phase which is as follows:

```
    // create a new span for displaying result of the end-user attempt, set id and append it to the div
    var rSpan= document.createElement("span");
    $(rSpan).attr("id" ,"result");
    $(newDiv).append(rSpan);
    // append each div to the game board        
    $("#gameboard").append(newDiv);
}
```

is there something unusual that is there I am not getting the resultant span, whenever I make a wrong combination in the game.

more code

```
/* 
 * Create the game board, includes 
 * one line to display the code images - "coderow"
 * 8 attempts
 * 1 accept button
 * 8 peg selections
 */
function createGameBoard(){

    //add code images (dummy code)
    for (var i = 1; i <= CODE_LENGTH; i++){
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        $(newImg).attr("id", "code" + i);
        //add a dummy image
        $(newImg).attr("src", "./images/hole.png");
        $("#coderow").append(newImg);
    }

    //add attempts
    for (var i = NUM_ATTEMPTS; i > 0; i--){
        //for each attempt, we create a div
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        // set its id and class. Hint: to set its class, you can write: $(newDiv).attr("class", "attempt");
        $(newDiv).attr("class", "attempt");
        $(newDiv).attr("id", "attempt" + i);
        // create a span, and set its id and class
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        $(newSpan).attr("class", "c1");
        $(newSpan).attr("id", "attempt" + i + "pegs");

        // then add 5 images including ids and classes. The img source could be empty or could be the hole.png
        for (var j = 1; j <= CODE_LENGTH; j++){
            var newImg= document.createElement("img");
            $(newImg).attr("class" ,"imgAttempt");
            $(newImg).attr("id" ,"attempt" + i + "_" + j);
            $(newImg).attr("src", "./images/hole.png");
            $(newSpan).append(newImg);
        }
        //append the span to the div
        $(newDiv).append(newSpan);

        // create a new span for displaying result of the end-user attempt, set id and append it to the div
        var resSpan= document.createElement("span");
        $(resSpan).attr("id" , "result");
        $(resSpan).append(newDiv);
        // append each div to the game board        
        $("#gameboard").append(newDiv);
    }

    //add Accept button inside a <div>
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    $(newDiv).attr("id", "acceptcode");
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    //var newInput2 = document.createElement("input");
    $(newInput).attr("type", "button");
    $(newInput).attr("name", "Accept");
    $(newInput).attr("value", "Accept");

    //$(newInput2).attr("type", "button");
    //$(newInput2).attr("id", "Hint");
    //$(newInput2).attr("value", "Hint");

    $(newInput).click(process_attempt); // set onclick event handler
    //$(newInput).click(hintMe); // set onclick event handler

    $(newDiv).append(newInput);
    //$(newDiv).append(newInput2);

    // add this button div to the game board
    $("#gameboard").append(newDiv);

    // add peg selection    
    // create 8 img elements and 
    // show each of the 8 marbles images with shadow from the images folder, also set their id and event handler 
    for (var i = 1; i <= NUM_BALLS; i++){
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        $(newImg).attr("id", "shadow" + i); 
        $(newImg).attr("src", "./images/shadow_ball_" + i + ".png");
        // set onclick event handler and pass event.data.id as a parameter
        $(newImg).click({id: i}, select_peg); 
        $("#pegselection").append(newImg);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, please [edit] and include the HTML structure with the expected result and the actual one. I suspect that you're adding multiple elements with the same ID to the DOM, but I can't tell for sure if this got anything to do with the actual problem

Comment: thanks for looking up. I can not add the image as do have 10 rep yet but if you search in a code breaker game, when e put up a combination there should be a resulting peg and ball comes up to tell that if its a right combination or wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you need exactly but to add a span in jquery all you need is this: [Append in end of div](https://api.jquery.com/append/).  From the docs: ```$(".container").append($( "span" ));
 ``` Will append a span in the end of the div with the class ```.container```. Another way to use it is ```$(".container").append( `<span>hello</span>`); ```